# Jquery Dialog dynamic elements inside

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-dialog

im trying to create jquery ui dialogs with buttons and events inside, this code works, but how can i add more divs or buttons inside #info div. If i add a input type="checkbox" inside the #info div in the html code. The popup will just be blank with no content at all.
How can i add more elements inside the html?

```
for (var i = 0; i < newsArray.length; i++) {

   var dialogHTML = $('.dialog').html();

   $('.info').html(newsArray[i].NewsText);

   $(dialogHTML).dialog({

      resizable: true,
      width: "auto",
      modal: true,
      title: newsArray[i].Title
   });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="dialog" style="display:none;"> 
<div class="info"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are not limited to using [.html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/) to assign content to a jQuery object, have you looked at [.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/)?

Comment: First of all, something seems very wrong with this loop logic. It's like youre trying to create dialogs for each element but actually the only difference between loop steps is changing `$('.info').html()` and dialog's title. And `$(dialogHTML).dialog` seems also wrong too.

Comment: I have a dynamic array, wich i looping through to get the information from.